# Azure DevOps REST API - How are Picklists associated with Field?

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I am trying to use rest to create fields and picklists, on the web site I created a field as type picklist String and added some items to the list: 
[image: custom field as picklist String with some picklist items]

Rest url for field:
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workitemtypes/CMMI2.Bug/fields/Custom.AppType?api-version=5.0-preview.2

it is returning this:

```
{
referenceName: "Custom.AppType",
name: "AppType",
type: "string",
description: "",
url: "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/work/processes/bd96307e-3d16-44ac-b498-be1a8daff2d5/behaviors",
customization: "custom"
}
```

Rest URL for picklist:
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/work/processes/lists/{picklistId}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
this returns:

```
{
items: [
"All",
"Item2",
"Item3"
],
id: "{picklistId}",
name: "picklist_{diffGuidFromPickListId}",
type: "String",
isSuggested: false,
url: "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/work/processes/lists/{picklistId}"
}
```

Here is documentation for this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#processworkitemtypefield

Firstly - why is type of field string when it should be picklistString (as per documentation link)?

Secondly - how is the picklist linked to the field?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The picklistString refers to the name of the type, its actual property is string, so the field type it displays in type is string.

> Secondly - how is the picklist linked to the field?

(1) To achieve this, you can use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
POST  https://dev.azure.com/{organizationName}/{projectName}/_apis/wit/fields?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

Here is my request body for you reference:

```
{
  "name": "{FieldName}",
  "referenceName": "{the reference name of WIT},
  "type": "string",
  "usage": "workItem",
  "readOnly": false,
  "canSortBy": true,
  "isQueryable": true,
  "supportedOperations": [
    {
      "referenceName": "{the reference name of WIT}"
      "name": "="
    }
  ],
  "isIdentity": true,
  "isPicklist": true,
  "isPicklistSuggested": false,
  "url": null
}
```

**Note**: Set **isPicklist** as `true`, and you can link picklist to this new field.

(2) For UI operation, just add new field, open the drop-down list of **type** and select picklist(string)/picklist(Integer) as what you need.

The difference between `picklist(string)` and `picklist(Integer)` is that [`picklist(string)` allow a pick list of short text string (255 characters or less) values, and `picklist(Integer)` contains a pick list of Integer values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-operators-variables?view=azure-devops).

Comment: thank you for response.  how exactly do I associate a field with an existing picklist in the UI?

Comment: Ohh, sorry. After further research and discuss with colleague, I got a solved solution. Please try with my updated answer to view whether it can help you link picklist  to field.

Comment: thanks for reply but I am a little confused, I don't see in your request body how you associate field with picklist?  Or add items to the picklist for that field?  I would think you would need to specify picklist id??

Comment: also - how can I manage this api with VssConnection.GetClient<>  ?

Comment: The filedname is specified in the body, and the filed and the picklist are connected by isPicklist: true .

Comment: thanks for reply hugh but that is not really clear.  can you be more specific please?

Comment: In the request body I defined the field with the name FieldName, then I set the isPicklist to true below, so the field type is the picklist, which is equivalent to you customize a field in the UI interface to select the Type as Picklist.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that this is all moot, since the `picklistId` property cannot be changed once it has been set (i.e. at field creation).

In this reference material, `picklistId` has "No" as its value for the "Can change?" column: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/work-item-fields?view=azure-devops